# Selecting same column twice from a single table but with different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I would like to display names and numbers of employees with numbers and names of their bosses, like below:

[image: output]

There is only one table:

[image: table]

I tried this so far:

```
SELECT  
    ID, 
    Name, 
    Boss, 
    (SELECT Name FROM Employees WHERE ID IN (SELECT Boss FROM Employees))
FROM Employees
```

But it gives me an error:

> *"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression"*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a self-join; something like:

```
Select a.ID, a.Name, b.ID as Boss, b.Name as BossName
from Employees A
left join Employees B
on a.Boss = b.ID
```

Comment: Hi @csharp_devloper31; I am sorry to hear this isn't working for you, but won't be able to help without more information.  Considering that the answer is a couple years old at this point, I suggest posting a new question including your code and whatever error/unexpected results you are getting.  See [ASK] for details.

Comment: I have already posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66336049/how-to-can-select-the-same-column-with-two-different-condition-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment117277684_66336049

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to limit the sub-query to return the first result only using a `TOP` clause.  You need to join it to the main table as well:

```
SELECT
    e.ID, 
    e.Name, 
    e.Boss, 
    (SELECT top 1 Name FROM Employees b where b.ID = e.Boss) as BossName
FROM Employees e
```

Comment: Using top without an order by is generally not a good approach. If the query returns more than 1 row you have now way of ensuring which row is returned. But in this case it would probably work.

Comment: or just `distinct` instead of `top 1`

Comment: @SeanLange - I agree that in general the left-join approach is preferred, but in this case the results will be identical presuming that ID is the primary key. Because we are filtering by ID here, the result of the nested query will always contain 0 or 1 records.

Answer (score 2):

I actually had to create a similar split in my Azure DB. Separating genders (men & Women) using their title.

[image]

Here is the bit of code.

```
select 
    (Select count(b.TITLE) from SalesLT.Customer b Where Title LIKE 'Mr%') as women 
    ,(Select count(c.TITLE) from SalesLT.Customer c Where Title LIKE 'Ms%') as men
    ,(Select count(d.TITLE) from SalesLT.Customer d Where Title NOT LIKE 'Ms%' AND Title NOT LIKE 'Mr%' ) as unidentified 
    ,count(a.TITLE) as Total
from SalesLT.Customer a
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

APH's answer is definitely the most effective solution. However, I would like to add a solution with a correlated subquery to show that you have been quite close to a working query.

```
SELECT
    E.ID, 
    E.Name, 
    E.Boss,
    (SELECT Name FROM Employees WHERE ID = E.Boss) AS BossName
 FROM Employees E
```

The problem with your original query was that the condition in the subquery did not depend on the specific record. The subquery returned the name of every employee who is the boss of someone else.

Please note that this solution usually has a worse performance than the join because it has to execute the subquery  for every item. Although the result is equivalent to that of the join many optimizers do not realize this because they do not touch subqueries.