# How to can select the same column with two different condition SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `test` contains these columns:

```
Id(int)     AddAt (datetime)     state (bit)
```

I have a list of times (`clockIn` and `clockOut`), and I would to separate them and create new columns called `ClockIn` and `ClockOut`.

- If state = 0, select AddAt as ClockIn
- If state = 1, select AddAt as ClockOut

What I have tried:

```
select 
    Id,
    (select AddAt from test where state = 0) as ClockIn,
    (select AddAt from test where state = 1) as ClockOut
from 
    test
```

but this does not work for me. What can I do to get this to work?

**Update :**

After testing the solution , I got this result . It seems works but I would like to replace these `Null` value since that ID is related to a person and I would like to make the `ClockIn` and `ClockOut` compatible.

[image]

**Update 2:**

After testing the `LEAD\LAG` solution , that's what I got:

[image]

I will try to explain what I need exactly , this is the result of the solution ( case max ) and what I need now is summarize the data ( see the image below ) , I'm trying to get only one row for the ID = 1 and only one row for the ID = 2 , why I got NULL values ???

[image]

What I got :

```
    id  employee_code   status          created

1   EMP0001         check_in        2016-08-20 09:30:30
2   EMP0001         check_out       2016-08-20 18:15:00
3   EMP0002         check_in        2016-08-21 14:52:48
4   EMP0002         check_out       2016-08-21 21:09:18
```

The expected result

```
employee_code   check_in_at            check_out_at           total_time

EMP0002         2016-08-21 14:52:48    2016-08-21 21:09:18    06:16:30
EMP0001         2016-08-20 09:30:30    2016-08-20 18:15:00    08:44:30
```

How can I do that???

I have edited my question many times , but I didn't get an answer to my question??!!!!

Comment: Please explain what "does not work for me" means.  An error?  If so, what?  Incorect data?  If so what?

Comment: Can you use `CASE-WHEN` construct?

Comment: Your sample data does not conform to the question.  Where is `id`?

Comment: ID is the Person ID , I didn't take a screenshot for this column sorry

Comment: What is not working about the `LEAD` solution? It looks correct, without input data and expected output I can only assume there is a missing `ClockOut`

Comment: First of all, the data are not compatible , the data of the clockout should be for the ID 1 not 2. Secondly, and there is a NULL value , ( expected result should be not null since I have a clockout time for the ID 1 )

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't have any data to test, I can't test it, but here is what I think you need

```
select id,
       case when state = 0 then AddAt else null end ClockIIn,
       case when state = 1 then AddAt else null end ClockIOut
  from test;
```

Comment: `else` value is `null` by default.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks. It's just me preferring no defaults but specify values explicitly

Comment: I have tested your solution and I have some remarks , could please see the update that I've added to my question?

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 Though I don't get what di you mean saying "compatible" but you can replace "nulls"  with any value you need to make it compatible

Comment: The `ID` represent a person , so what I got is a reputation for the same ID , I got two rows with the same ID ( the first row has Null value in ClockIN column and the second row has Null value in ClockOut column ), what I need is merge the two data and remove the null values and the result in this case will be one row with two filled columns ( ClockIN and ClockOUT)

Answer (score 0):

Naively, conditional aggregation may do what you want:

```
select Id,
       max(case when state = 0 then addat end) as  ClockIn,
       max(case when state = 1 then addat end) as ClockOut
from test 
group by id;
```

I say "naively" because you have not really specified what the data looks like (by giving examples) and what results you really want.

Comment: I have edit and update my question , could you see please again my question after the update?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need `LEAD/LAG` here:

***EDIT 2:*** it seems that the `Id` column is the primary key, there is a `employee_code` which is a foreign key, and we need the result to be `PARTITION BY employee_code`.

```sql
select 
    employee_code,
    ClockIn,
    ClockOut
from (
    select 
        employee_code,
        created as ClockIn,
        Status,
        LEAD(CASE WHEN status = 'check_out' THEN created END) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_code ORDER BY created) as ClockOut
    from test
) t
WHERE t.Status = 'check_in';
```

If you want a total clocking time across each `employee_code`, you can `GROUP BY employee_code` then select `SUM(DATEDIFF(second, ClockIn, ClockOut))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is incorrect and does not work for me.

Comment: The ID is a primary key not a foreign key and I test the solution now but I didn't get any result in the column of Clock Out

Comment: You have a non-unique PK?? I ask you again, please [edit] your question and supply sample data and expected output, otherwise how can we know exactly what you want?

Comment: I edited my question , could you please see the update?

Comment: OK should work now. **In future please give `CREATE TABLE` definitions and sample data right from the start, we can't help unless we know what exactly you want** Giving us only half the information that makes a difference is not much help. See how to make a [mcve]